# Specific pop up with ajax and query from database

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use in a form a simple radio button with "YES" or "No", I wish that when I click yes a pop-up window will be automatically shown with this specific message:

`Are you sure you want to sell a new membership to [User’s Full Real Name from database] with the number [ number of product from database ] ?`

That means at the same time an ajax query will be established to return the name of user and the number of product from database.

I'm not very good in JS/Ajax, can anyone help me with this?

Edit :

I know to do what you wrote in the message bellow,what I'm not sure is how to run the pop-up window automatically when I choose "yes" radio button?

Comment: In order to look up the username and productID from the database, you'll need some sort of identifier to start with. What information is already available on the page to use in the database query? Perhaps you can just share the code from the page?

Comment: I can get the Id of user already connected from URL with GET method and I'll use it to fetch data from database!

Comment: In that case, you could also look up the user name and the product ID when you initially load the page (using PHP or whatever scripting engine), rather than when the user clicks on the radio button. This will be more reliable and easier than an ajax call.

Comment: Ok I can get also username and product ID from database so without using ajax call but until now I don't know how to do it with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use ajax, you first need to create a server-side function that does what you need. For instance, a php script that takes a userID and returns the user's full name. Let's suppose you create that script and call it "username.php".

On your page, you'll use a javascript function, such as the jquery [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to send an asynchronous request to username.php. The function call will look something like this:

```
function lookupUsername(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "username.php",
      data: { ID: $("#userID").val() }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Username: " + msg );
    });
}
```

In the above example, I've assumed that the user ID is embedded somewhere on your page in an element with `ID="userID"`. The term `$("#userID").val()` is a jQuery function that looks up the value of the HTML element called "userID".

Next, you need to call the lookup function when the yes radio button is clicked. So something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo" value="yes" onclick="lookupUsername()" />
```

Note that to use the JQuery framework (The .ajax() function and the $() selector function, you need to include the JQuery framework on your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

It's totally possible to do an ajax call without jQuery, but the code is a little messier.